# How to define a dependency between two coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Consider the following code:

```
init {
     // coroutine 1
     // this is and needs to be in a separate coroutine as the collection runs indefinite
    viewModelScope.launch {
        myService.someSharedFlow.collect {
            // handle values
        }
    }

    // coroutine 2
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // this shall not be executed before the subscription to the SharedFlow in coroutine 1 is set up
        // to make sure I don't miss any emitted values
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            myService.initialize() // will send a value through the flow after initialization
        }
    }
}
```

How can I let coroutine 2 wait until the subscription to the SharedFlow in coroutine 1 is set up?

Comment: Why have you posted the same question twice ? Please remove one of them, to avoid confusion for readers, and allow a centralized discussion over the subject.

Comment: thanks for the hint, other question deleted.

Comment: I don't say this is wrong, but it feels somehow strange that the service has to wait until it is observed. Normally, when using hot flows, producer doesn't care that much on whether there are consumers and how many. What is your exact use case? Maybe it would make more sense to use `Channel` here?

Comment: Also, you can look into [onSubscription()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-subscription.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for a collector to subscribe on your flow before pushing values in it, I see two solutions:

1. If you have a `MutableSharedFlow`, you can use [subscriptionCount](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/subscription-count.html) property to know if your flow has been subscribed to.
2. As @broot said, there's also the possibility to use [onSubscription](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-subscription.html) on a `SharedFlow`. This does not require to expose mutable API. However, if there can be multiple collectors, and you want to ensure initialization is triggered only once, you will have to add some manual checks over it.

Here is a sample program that show how to use both solutions:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

fun main() : Unit = runBlocking {
    val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    println(
        """
        Solution 1: subscriptionCount
        -----------------------------
        """.trimIndent())
    waitForSubsciptionCount(flow)

    println(
        """
        
        Solution 2: onSubscription
        -----------------------------
        """.trimIndent())
    reactToSubscription(flow)
}

suspend fun CoroutineScope.waitForSubsciptionCount(flow: MutableSharedFlow<Int>) {
    val collectJob = collectAfterDelay(flow)

    println("Waiting for subscription")
    flow.subscriptionCount.filter { it > 0 }.first()

    println("Subscription detected")
    flow.initialize()

    // Specific to this test program, to avoid it to hang indefinitely
    collectJob.cancel()
}

suspend fun CoroutineScope.reactToSubscription(flow: SharedFlow<Int>) {
    println("Waiting for subscription")

    // This is optional. Helps to detect "end" of the flow.
    val initialized = MutableStateFlow(false)

    val initializableFlow = flow.onSubscription {
        println("Subscription detected")
        initialize()
        initialized.emit(true)
    }

    val collectJob = collectAfterDelay(initializableFlow)

    // Specific to this test program, to avoid it to  indefinitely
    initialized.filter { it == true }.first()
    collectJob.cancel()
}

private fun CoroutineScope.collectAfterDelay(flow: Flow<Int>) = launch {
    delay(1.seconds)
    print("Start collecting")
    flow.collect { println("collected: $it") }
}

suspend fun FlowCollector<Int>.initialize() {
    for (i in 1..3) {
        emit(i)
        println("Emitted $i")
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Solution 1: subscriptionCount
-----------------------------
Waiting for subscription
Start collectingSubscription detected
collected: 1
Emitted 1
collected: 2
Emitted 2
collected: 3
Emitted 3

Solution 2: onSubscription
-----------------------------
Waiting for subscription
Start collectingSubscription detected
collected: 1
Emitted 1
collected: 2
Emitted 2
collected: 3
Emitted 3
```

*NOTE*: Both solutions above should also allow you to move initialization trigger inside your service, and hide it completely from consumers. This way, code calling your service would not require to mangle with your service initialization.

**EDIT**: Here is an example of a service that triggers flow emission after a subscriber start collecting:

```kotlin
class SubscriptionCountService {
    private val _flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    public  val  flow = _flow.asSharedFlow()

    init {
        _flow.subscriptionCount.filter { it > 0 }
                               .take(1)
                               .onCompletion {
                                   println("First subscription detected: initialize")
                                   _flow.initialize() 
                               }
                               .launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO))
    }
}


fun main() : Unit = runBlocking {
    val flow = SubscriptionCountService().flow
    launch {
        delay(1.seconds)
        println("Start collecting")
        // Collect a limited number of entries to terminate main program easily
        flow.take(3)
            .collect { println("collected: $it") }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Start collecting
collected: 1
Emitted 1
collected: 2
Emitted 2
collected: 3
Emitted 3
```